# Graphview in Eclipse Can the X & Y Axis use different LabelFormats?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-graphview

I have a graph and I need the Y axis to display to 1dp. This works by doing the following code.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter(nf, nf));
```

I need the X axis to display 2 strings, 1 at the beginning and 1 at the end. This works by doing the following code.

```
StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);
staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {firstStr,lastStr});
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(2);
```

My problem is I can't do both on the same graph!

Both work individually but not together, any ideas gratefully recieved

I am using version 4.0 of Graphview

Answer (score 0):

yes you can combine the static labels and dynamic labels.

Use the StaticLabelFormatter and set the dyamic label formatter.
http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/helper/StaticLabelsFormatter.html#setDynamicLabelFormatter-com.jjoe64.graphview.LabelFormatter-

Something like this should work:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);

StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);
staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {firstStr,lastStr});
staticLabelsFormatter.setDynamicLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter(nf, nf));
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(2);
```

Documentation
http://www.android-graphview.org/documentation/label-formatter